# Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) Reserve VMs?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

my question is:

How do I reserve Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) VMs?

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/

In the pricing calculator show that I can Reserve VMs for 3 years, that exists when buying VMs, but have no when buying AKS

What is the flow?

I should reserve as VM then call support and transfer them from ASK flow?

I am asking here this question because Microsoft has link Stackoverflow is "community" forum

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/community/

[image]

Comment: I suggest you open a billing support ticket (free to do), to ask about reserve instance pricing, discounts, etc.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/prepay-reserved-vm-instances?toc=/azure/billing/TOC.json#next-steps

After you buy reservations they are applied automatically to the VMs you are buying: The reservation discount is applied automatically to the number of running virtual machines that match the reservation scope and attributes.

So you just have to buy adequate reservations that are scoped properly

Comment: Thank you, I was looking two days for this answer 10x

Comment: Thx for the link, this is exactly what I was looking for!